# Load image previously saved at gallery

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I want to save an image to my gallery and load it after. If possible I want to load it without even needing to select it with the UI.

The idea behind this is to have an app that works without internet connection and store images (that's why I am thinking about the gallery). Once you have internet connection the idea is to pick up all the images saved from the gallery and push them somewhere.

I've tried using React Native Expo with expo-media-library, expo-camera and expo-image-picker but I can't make it.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are asking about how to save an image to local storage and retrieve it back later programatically.

Here are the steps:

1. Save the image bitmap to file.
2. Save the path string containing where you stored it to Shared preferences.
3. In the future, load that image using the path address, and do whatever you want with it.

Take a look at the [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) library. It does most of these for you on one line of code